# Python explode a string to separate urls from text

Tags: python

Actually I use a script like this to extract urls from a string:

```
import re
s = 'This is my tweet check it out http://www.example.com/blah and http://blabla.com'
result = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', s)
print(result)
['http://www.example.com/blah', 'http://blabla.com']
```

Now i need to evolve the script and i need to create a dictionary for each chunk of my string: i need to recognize urls from normal text BUT i need to maintain normal text also, and split original string to a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict_result = {
 0: {
      type: "text",
      value: "This is my tweet check it out"
    },
 1: {
      type: "url",
      value: "http://www.example.com/blah"
    },
 2: {
      type: "text",
      value: "and"
    },
 3: {
      type: "url",
      value: "http://blabla.com"
    }
}
```

but i don't understand if exist a function to simplify my work. I can accept also a result like a list if it is not possible to create a dict like mine, then I can iterate the list and check if it is a url or text and create my dict later.

Anyone with an idea of what function can i use to achieve this? Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For splitting text so it consist of substrings of interests and other parts, you might use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with first argument having capturing group - which you already have, so you could do:

```
import re
s = 'This is my tweet check it out http://www.example.com/blah and http://blabla.com'
result = re.split(r'(https?://\S+)', s)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['This is my tweet check it out ', 'http://www.example.com/blah', ' and ', 'http://blabla.com', '']
```

Note that what was matched by pattern has always odd index number, even if it is begin of string that is:

```
s = 'http://www.example.com something http://www.blahblahblah.com'
result = re.split(r'(https?://\S+)', s)
print(result)
```

gives:

```
['', 'http://www.example.com', ' something ', 'http://www.blahblahblah.com', '']
```